Can cats skip clopidogrel doses
I have two cats, one of which has just been diagnosed with HCM. She's been prescribed clopidogrel tablets, which I crush up an mix in to wet food. I'm going away for a week and my neighbour would normally feed my cats. I'm slightly hesitant to ask her to deliver the meds and ensure that only the correct cat eats it etc.
So my questions are: Can doses be skipped? If she only had one every other day then would that be a big deal? Could they even just be skipped for the entire week? If she just mixes the meds in to some cat food and they both end up eating it then would the other non HCM cat be ok?
Thanks,
Joe

Fixing typo:
This is one i would ask the vet. There are cat dishes that recognize the cat's chip and open only for specific cats, but they aren't cheap and it can take a few weeks to accustom the cats to the motorized lid. There are other ways to do differential feeding, including separating the cats into different rooms and feeding them there, but that requires a cat-sitter willing to make some extra effort

One can also find a cat-sitter who knows how to pill a cat without becoming someone the dat hides from. They do exist; I've dealt with both pills and subcutaneous injections when looking after friend's cats while their owners were out of town.
